South Indian Movie where father enters Yagna fire to bring rain to village hit by drought?
I'm 99% sure that this is a Malayalam movie. It should be from 1970's or 1980's.
In this movie, a son doesn't listen to his father and always challenges the mystical powers of the mantra and Yagna.
One fine day, to relieve a drought in their village, the father raises a big Yagna. Of course, his son mocks him.
But the father enters Yagna and, contrary to the son's belief, the village gets rain from nowhere. In the next scene, the son becomes the new astrologer of that village.
Can you please help me identify this movie?

I think the movie is ' Paithrukam'.
Directed by Jayaraj in 1993.
Language: Malayalam
The movie is about a traditional brahmin family of kerala and their fights between religious beliefs  and atheism.
Starring :
Suresh gopi,
Jayaram,
Narendra prasad,
Maniyan pilla raju,
Geetha

